# Run assertions directly in browser context in Playwright

Tags: javascript, testing, cypress, playwright

I would like to test some apis which are tied directly into browser and not necessary have UI representation.

Simpliest test beeing something like:

```js
import { test, expect } from "@playwright/test";

test("creates Image element", async ({ page }) => {
  await page.goto(`http://localhost:3333/e2e/assets/Dynamic.spec.html`);

  const img = new Image();
  const asset = new DynamicAsset(img);

  expect(asset.element()).toEqual(img);
});
```

When using cypress, all the tests are run in browser context. That would work.

But in playwright following error occurs:

```
ReferenceError: Image is not defined

    at file:///Users/tomche/development/frontendara/amandes/e2e/assets/Dynamic.spec.js:6:15
```

And if using `page.evaluate` like:

```js
import { test, expect } from "@playwright/test";

test("creates Image element", async ({ page }) => {
  await page.goto(`http://localhost:3333/e2e/assets/Dynamic.spec.html`);

  await page.evaluate(() => {
    const img = new Image();
    const asset = new DynamicAsset(img);

    expect(asset.element()).toEqual(img);
  });
});
```

Error is:

```
page.evaluate: ReferenceError: expect is not defined
```

Which is happening since code evaluated in browser context doesn't have imports from upper scope.

Documentation seems to mention only things which are serialisable, but this code needs complex things to be verified which are not really mockable in node or serializable.

So is there a way to run assertions inside the browser similar to cypress/karma etc.?

Comment: Have you tried dynamic imports? Just spitballing...

Answer (score 2):

Running full test code as updated, can get expect to work outside of `evaluate()`

(But note I have a different error message from original)

```js
import { test, expect } from "@playwright/test";

test("creates Image element", async ({ page }) => {
  await page.goto(`http://localhost:3333/e2e/assets/Dynamic.spec.html`);

  const result = await page.evaluate(() => {
    const img = new Image();
    const asset = new DynamicAsset(img);
    return {img, asset}
  });

  expect(result.asset.element()).toEqual(result.img);
});
```

Comment: This won't work, as mentioned in my first example. I've updated to include the import for clarity.

Comment: I added your test, the error for Image does not occur. Intellisense shows `var Image: new (width?: number, height?: number) => HTMLImageElement`

Comment: intelissense != runtime. I've provided error which occurs if you run it.

Comment: Plus if you do have the import, how can you get `ReferenceError: expect is not defined`?

Comment: Please read the examples which I provided. Second example is using `page.evaluate` Update to full version as well for clarity

Comment: It works ok in my test, thanks.

Comment: See [this runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77483440/6243352) showing that this assertion gives a false positive.

Answer (score 2):

Pass `expect` into `page.evaluate()`

```js
import { test, expect } from "@playwright/test";

test("creates Image element", async ({ page }) => {
  await page.goto(`http://localhost:3333/e2e/assets/Dynamic.spec.html`);

  await page.evaluate((expect) => {
    const img = new Image();
    const asset = new DynamicAsset(img);

    expect(asset.element()).toEqual(img);
  }, expect);
});
```

Comment: This won't work as well, `expect` is no serialisable. Getting `Error: Unexpected value` and it works as described in docs https://playwright.dev/docs/evaluating#evaluation-argument

Answer (score 1):

The golden rule of Playwright, Puppeteer and other backend-based browser automation libraries is: keep browser stuff in the browser, and keep backend stuff in the backend. The only way to move data back and forth between the browser process and the backend process is with serialization and deserialization (stringification and destringification if you prefer) over a network socket.

For OP's use case, the existing answers won't work because they attempt to send or return complex, non-serializable objects as strings through a network socket.

In the "return browser objects back to Node" solution, even if you could serialize the objects and reconstruct them in Node, identities would no longer match. Even if the identities did match, the whole point of testing is to deal with the JS running in a website in the browser. If it was a test you could perform using Node objects, there'd be little point to using Playwright. A simple Jest unit test in pure Node would be the way to go.

In the "pass a Playwright assertion into the browser", even if you could serialize everything the object would need to have to report an error back to Node, which it's not designed to do.

The correct approach to the scenario at hand is to perform the equality check in the browser, where the objects live, then return a simple, serializable boolean back to Node for the assertion:

```js
import {expect, test} from "@playwright/test"; // ^1.39.0

test("creates Image element", async ({page}) => {
  await page.goto("http://localhost:3333/e2e/assets/Dynamic.spec.html");

  const isAssetElementEqualToImg = await page.evaluate(() => {
    const img = new Image();
    const asset = new DynamicAsset(img);
    return asset.element() === img;
  });
  expect(isAssetElementEqualToImg).toBe(true);
});
```

A custom error message can be useful for improving the readability of the assertion failure message:

```js
test("creates Image element", async ({page}) => {
  await page.goto("http://localhost:3333/e2e/assets/Dynamic.spec.html");

  const eq = await page.evaluate(() => {
    const img = new Image();
    const asset = new DynamicAsset(img);
    return asset.element() === img;
  });
  expect(eq, "asset.element() === img was false").toBe(true);
});
```

This is fine for OP's specific scenario, since the predicate can be determined synchronously, but for other tests that involve real-time asynchronous work, you may want to poll or use a custom matcher to wait for the assertion to pass.

Here's a minimal example showing that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71633640/6243352) gives a false positive, as it treats any Node references as identical:

```js
import {expect, test} from "@playwright/test";

const html = `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script>
img = new Image();
para = document.createElement("p");
</script>
</body>
</html>`;

// incorrect, trying to return Nodes from `evaluate`:
test("fail: an image should not be equal to a paragraph", async ({page}) => {
  test.fail(); // this test should fail but doesn't
  await page.setContent(html);
  const {img, para} = await page.evaluate(() => {
    return {img, para};
  });
  await expect(img).toEqual(para);
});

// the correct approach, comparing in the browser environment:
test("an image should not be equal to a paragraph", async ({page}) => {
  await page.setContent(html);
  const eq = await page.evaluate(() => img === para);
  expect(eq).toBe(false);
});
```

Comment: Hey, I really appreciate taking the time to answer this and tbh don't know why I didn't figure it out myself.

But could you shorten it down to just answer how to achieve the desired outcome? I just feels that discussions on how e2e testing frameworks work shouldn't be part of this and proofs of why other answers won't work would be better as comments on the wrong answers maybe?

Comment: Thanks for responding. Sorry, I think the answer needs to be complete, because there's a good deal of misunderstanding in the thread that needs to be cleared up. Not only are the other answers outright wrong, they have many upvotes, not to mention [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71633602/run-assertions-directly-in-browser-context-in-playwright/77483440?noredirect=1#comment135640771_71633640) that can't possibly be right, also with upvotes. I already left a comment on one of the other answers explaining why it was wrong and upvoted existing comments that already state that.

Comment: If you're in a rush, just look at the first couple code blocks and ignore everything else.